# SAS PROC MEANS with selected columns to mean

Tags: sas

```
proc means data=tableepisodes noprint; 
output out=tableepisodes
mean(%ratings %dummies)=%ratings %dummies; 
by  ProgCodeID ProgSeasonCodeID year week
```

I was reading through a SAS code and I am not sure what the mean part of the code does ,

Is it that it only takes the mean of %ratings variables and attach the % dummies variables to the output ?

would really appreciate if I could get help in understanding this code snippet

Comment: Are you sure RATINGS and DUMMIES are macros and not macro variables?  If they are macro variables you would reference them as `&ratings` and `&dummies` instead.

Answer (score 1):

That isn't a complete code snippet, and no. 
It calculates the mean of the variables listed in %rating AND %dummies, assuming of course that's what is included in those macros.

Without seeing the macro definitions we can't be sure of what it is actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

As written, the code is going to evaluate the means of the variables stored inside the macro variables *ratings* and *dummies*. Taking *ratings* as an example, we're assuming it was defined earlier on as something like:

```
%let ratings = good bad ugly;
```

So, when you pass it through the proc means, *%ratings*  will evaluate to *good bad ugly* and SAS will take the means of all three variables.

You could have written the proc means function as:

```
proc means data = tableepisodes noprint;
    by ProgCodeID ProgSeasonCodeID year week;
    var good bad ugly;
    output out = tableepisodes mean= / autoname;
run;
```

instead. (Also, note that you're overwriting your original dataset here, which you may want to avoid.)

Comment: `%ratings` is not a macro variable reference, it is the invocation of a macro named ratings. Presumably, that macro will return a variable list.